# EFCore Removing DateTimeOffset's Specific Offset when deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

.NET 8 API writes to an Azure SQL database with tables that have a CreatedOn datetimeoffset(7) field to store date/time w/ offset. This field is set via EFCore on the OnBeforeSaving event:

```
entry.Property("CreatedOn").CurrentValue = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
```

When local environment writes to the Azure SQL database, EFCore generates a date/time with an offset: 2024-01-24 18:06:44.5682227 -05:00

When the code is deployed to the Azure environment, EFCore generates a date/time without the offset: 2024-01-24 23:15:04.7942096 +00:00

When marshalled back to a .NET DateTimeOffset field, the value is 2024-01-24 23:15:04.794209 *e.g. 11:23PM* which causes date/time comparisons to fail.

Is there a reason for this? Can I force the offset to ensure date/time comparisons are compared accurately?

Comment: Azure runs on the `+00:00` timezone. So of course your `Now` would be on the zero offset when run on Azure. But if you're doing your comparison properly, `18:00 -05:00` *should* be equal to `23:00 +00:00`

Comment: Running `DateTimeOffset.Parse("2024-01-01 18:00 -05:00").Equals(DateTimeOffset.Parse("2024-01-01 23:00 +00:00"))` would result in `True`

Comment: You can set the `TZ` environment variable to override the local timezone. But that shouldn't change how values are compared. Also note that the database server will have its own timezone...

Comment: @NPras Correct. I just realized the deployed environment was Azure and as you said it shouldn't matter if you code properly but I noticed the code base is using DateTime everywhere and a few instances where the DateTimeOffset was using the DateTime property which killed the offset. When compared to DateTime, the results were incorrect.

Example:

`DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, object.CreatedOn.GetValueOrDefault().AddMinutes(1).DateTime) > 0;
`

For DateTimeOffset usage, the code should not use DateTime correct? DateTimeOffset.Now, etc. should be used?